# Как по другому записать код что бы не выдавал ошибку?

Tags: php, ооп

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\Users\Filip\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\mynewchat.com\index.php on line 28

Я делаю код в котором с помощью методов человек вводит возраст , а метод checkAge() проверяет , что бы возраст был меньше 100 и больше 1

Код :

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php 

class Worker
{
private $name;
private $age;
private $salary;

public function GetName(){
return print $this->SetName();
}
public function SetName($name){
print $this->name = $name;
}
public function GetAge(){
return print $this->GetAge();    
}
public function SetAge($Age){
print $this->Age = $Age;
}
public function Getsalary(){
return print $this->Getsalary();    
}
public function SetSalary($salary){
print $this->salary = $salary;  
}
private function checkAge( GetAge($num) ){
    if(1>=$num && $num<=100){
        return print "Нормально!";
       }
      }
     }

    $object = new Worker();
    $object->checkAge(10);

    ?>
```

Comment: `checkAge( GetAge($num) ){` это что за фокус у вас? как это вы в сигнатуру функции вписываете вызов метода? Уберите описание класса в другой файл, Никто классы с html не мешает.

Comment: `return print $this->Getsalary();` вы в курсе , что тут рекурсия бесконечная? вернее, она довольно быстро кончится с одноименной этому сайту ошибкой

Comment: прочитайте сначала хоть какую-то документацию,литературу или еще что-то, что позволит вам понять, что вообще такое ООП и как этим пользоваться. Вам тут могут написать, как поправить код, но это не поможет вам осознать, какой бред у вас написан. И если ваша цель в том, чтобы хоть как то научиться писать, то начните с учебников.

Comment: я читаю книгу и документации , и я знаю что такое ООП и как этим пользоваться , когда мне скидуют решение я разбираю его , не надо показывать недовольствие , не проще просто объяснить как что делать ?

Comment: для начала отформатирууйте код. Далее вам вероятно надо создать объект, вызвать метод установки возраста, внутри него вызвать метод проверки. Если проверка прошла, установить значение, иначе, например, выбросить исключение. и условие проверки 1-100 у вас не корректно. `return print` не знаю где вы увидели, но тот источник лучше не читайте более

Comment: спасибо за советы , а книга "PHP: объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования" от Мэтт Зандстра , вроде как лучшая среди ООП

Comment: В книге Зандстры никогда такой ереси не было. А вы может и понимаете что в ООП, но не понимаете базовый синтаксис.

Comment: Но судя по тому что вы вызываете приватный метод снаружи, то в ООП тоже не все в порядке.

Comment: @u_mulder наверно я не так хорошо освоил базовые знания что бы лезть в книгу Зандстры , нужно еще подучить PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте рассмотрим все по порядку. Во-первых, вынесите свой класс в отдельный файл. Отделяйте мух от котлет. В одном месте вы пишите "библиотеку" в другом вы ее используете. В противном случае у вас не получится использовать данный класс в нескольких местах вашего приложения.

Далее, у вас есть класс с тремя приватными свойствами и публичными геттерами-сеттерами. Вроде все логично. Однако, посмотрите на ваши сеттеры:

```
public function GetName(){
    return print $this->SetName();
}
```

Что вы здесь пытаетесь вернуть, имя? вот его и верните `return $this->name;`  Почему вы внутри вдруг вызываете сеттер этого же свойства без аргументов?

Также относительно `return print ...`. Получите ли вы когда-нибудь `name` воспользовашись такой конструкцией? Давайте посмотрим [справку](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.print.php):

> Главное отличие от echo в том, что print принимает только один аргумент и всегда возвращает 1.

То есть при подобном написании ваши геттеры всегда будут возвращать 1 и все. Даже если рассмотреть нечто подобное с позиции логгирования при разработке, то это совершенно не поддерживаемая в дальнейшем конструкция. Логгирование должно быть легко отключаемо и настраиваемо, и уж тем более никак не должно внедряться в инструкцию возврата из метода.

Теперь перейдем к основному. У вас есть свойство Возрасть, процедура его установки (сеттер) и вы хотите его провалидировать. Логично было бы предположить, что код должен вести себя так, что вы просто устанавливаете значение, а уже внутри проверяется, валидный он или нет. Вы используете код так:

```
$w = new Worker();
$w->checkAge(10);
```

А надо бы использовать так:

```
$w = new Worker();
$w->setAge(10);
```

И там внутри уже проверить, корректно ли этот возраст задан, и если нет, то, например, выбросить исключение.

По факту синтаксической ошибки, которую выдает пхп. Вот ваша строка:

```
private function checkAge( GetAge($num) )
```

Это сигнатура функции, в скобках функции указываются ее аргументы. Почему же у вас там указан вызов какого-то `GetAge($num)`? То есть вызов метода, вместо описания аргументов? В этом месте физически не может быть исполняемого кода. Поэтому пхп и ругается, что ожидает увидеть либо признак начала переменной `$` либо ссылку `&` перед ним.

Напишем метод проверки возраста. Подобные функции возвращают результат проверки, обычно это "успех" или "неудача", то есть `true/false`. Также в случае ошибки, логично выбросить исключение, и пусть вызывающий код сам думает, что с ним делать, мы же только сигнализируем, что нам такой параметр не подходит. В целом в самой функции мы можем только проверить корректность:

```
private function checkAge($num){
    return $num >= 1 && $num <= 100);
}
```

Теперь вернемся к сеттеру, где будем эту логику проверять/

```
public function setAge($age){

     $isVvalid = $this->checkAge($age);

     if(!$isValid){
         throw new Exception("Некорректный возраст - $age)");
     }

     $this->age = $age;
}
```

Так что функция проверки не должна возарщать слов вида "нормально". Она должна вернуть признак того. пройдена проверка или нет, при необходимости дополнительно передав сведения о том, почему эта проверка завершилась неудачей. Зачастую для этих вещей создают собственные классы исключений, которые содержат сведения об ошибке.

Условно вы можете завести две функции проверки, минимального возараста и максимального, которые в случае неудачи сразу будут выбрасывать исключаения, И классы исключения для этого тоже можно завести

```
class EMinAgeException extends Exception { }
class EMaxAgeException extends Exception { }
```

а функции

```
private function checkMinAge($age){
     if($age < 1) throw new EMinAgeException();
     return true;
}
```

И аналогично для маскимума. А сеттер проверяет оба и устанавливает свойство:

```
public function setAge($age){
    if ( $this->checkMinAge($age) && $this->checkMaxAge($age)){
        $this->age = $age;
    }
}
```

Тогда вызывающий код на основе разных типов исключений может вести себя по разному, и реализовывать дальнейшую логику по разным сценарям.

```
$w = new Worker();
try {
   $w->setAge(200);
} 
catch (EMinAgeException $e){
    // вероятна ошибка указания возраста
}
catch (EMaxAgeException $e){
     // вы слишком стары для того-то
}
```

Comment: Боже мой , спасибо что ты есть !Все по полочкам разложил